# VB XML classes vs string classes

Tags: xml, vb.net

Searching the internet finds no less than 700 different ways and opinions to accomplish what I'm trying to do, and I would just like to know the simplest, most bullet-proof way possible.

Consider the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xmlCommands>
<command>
<core>
<host>foo</host>
</core>
<protectedServers>
<hostName>bar</hostName>
</protectedServers>
<name>DeleteAgent</name>
</command>
</xmlCommands>
```

I simply want to extract the string "bar," which is inside `<hostName></hostName>`
I can do this easily enough with simple string functions, but I'd like to do it with one of the .NET XML classes/methods.

Comment: That's not an xml file.  That's an xml fragment.  You're missing the xml directive.  And How about looking around in the System.Xml namespace to start with.

Comment: Do you want to get all Commands (it looks like xmlCommands can hold multiple commands)?

Comment: Look at the [`System.Xml` namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145036.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using XPATH:

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
  'N.B. Need to Import System.Xml
  Dim xdc As New XmlDocument
  xdc.Load("C:\Junk\Junk.XML")
  '1. Search for a node at a particular place
  Dim strXpath1 As String = "/xmlCommands/command/protectedServers/hostName" 'N.B. case sensitive
  Dim xnd1 As XmlNode = xdc.SelectSingleNode(strXpath1)
  If xnd1 IsNot Nothing Then
    MsgBox(xnd1.FirstChild.Value)
  Else
    MsgBox(strXpath1 & " not found")
  End If
  '2. Search for first match in document
  Dim strXpath2 As String = "//hostName" 'N.B. case sensitive
  Dim xnd2 As XmlNode = xdc.SelectSingleNode(strXpath2)
  If xnd2 IsNot Nothing Then
    MsgBox(xnd2.FirstChild.Value)
  Else
    MsgBox(strXpath2 & " not found")
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to XML for this:

```
dim xDoc as xdocument = xdocument.parse(myXmlFile)
dim bar = (from y in xDoc.descendant("hostName") _
           select y.Value _
          ).take(1).singleordefault
```

or the traditional XML classes:

```
dim xDoc as new xml.xmldocument()
xDoc.Load(myXmlFile)
dim node as xml.xmlnode = xdoc.selectSingleNode(xPathStringtoNode)
dim bar as string = node.value
```

Comment: `dim xDoc as new xml.xmldocument(myXmlFile)` doesn't seem to be the right way to do this. The method doesn't take a string.

Comment: Ah, needed `xDoc.Load(path to file)`

Comment: Eh, sorry. Haven't tried the Linq example, but your second one doesn't work. Even after I add the missing `xDoc.Load`, `Dim node As Xml.XmlNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//hostName")` returns an empty string.

Comment: This works: `Dim node As XmlNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//hostName").ChildNodes(0)` all due respect, you really should take the time to test your code before you post it.

Comment: Replace mXmlFile with "//xmlCommands/command/protectedServers/hostName"